# Model Binding not working ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, binding, model, http-post

I have this model:

```
public class TaskCreation
{
    public task_description task_desc { get; set; }
    public List<Metric> metric { get; set; }
    public List<Context> context { get; set; }
    public int scenarioId { get; set; }
    public short meas_id { get; set; }

}
public class Metric
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
public class Context
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string values { get; set; }
    public string upper_bound { get; set; }
    public string lower_bound { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my controller methods:

```
public ActionResult CreateTask2()
    {
        TaskCreation tc = new TaskCreation();
        tc = TempData["TCObject"] as TaskCreation;
        return View(tc);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateTask2(TaskCreation TaskCreation)
    {
        //some code
    }
```

So the view receives a TaskCreation object and there are fields to enter a value for each metric and values, upper and lower bound for each context but in the [httppost] CreateTask2 the metric and context objects are null! Others attributes in the task_description object are binded correctly! How I can solve it?

This is my view:

```
@model Project.Models.TaskCreation
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateTask2", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) 
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">

    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
 <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.task_desc.Is_valid, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.task_desc.Is_valid)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.task_desc.Is_valid)
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.task_desc.repeat_interval, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.task_desc.repeat_interval)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.task_desc.repeat_interval)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <p>Enter the metrics values:</p>
    </div>
    @foreach(var m in Model.metric)
    {
        <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label(m.name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(x => m.value, new { placeholder = "Value" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => m.value)
        </div>
            <br />
    </div>
    }
    <div class="form-group">
        <p>Choose the constraints for each context:</p>
    </div>
        @foreach(var c in Model.context)
    {
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.Label(c.name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(con => c.lower_bound, new { placeholder = "Lower Bound" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(con => c.lower_bound)<br />
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(con => c.higher_bound, new { placeholder = "Upper Bound" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(con => c.higher_bound)
                            </td>
                            <td>OR</td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(con => c.values, new { placeholder = "Selected Values Separated by Spaces" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(con => c.values)
                            </td>
                            <br />
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
    }
     <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" />
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
}
```

Thank You

Comment: Have you solved your problem using my answer?

Comment: I'm sorry I was away for a couple of days, I will try it now! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of Foreach, use For loop -

```
  @for( int i = 0; i < Model.metric.Count; i++)
    {
        <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label(Model.metric[i].name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.metric[i].value, new { placeholder = "Value" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.metric[i].value)
        </div>
            <br />
    </div>
    }
```

Similarly you can go ahead for context property too.

**UPDATE:** Please check below sample on how to get the properties of Child Models in the Parent model. We can use FOR loop to iterate the child models. If we use For loop, we can get the values of child model on the server side without any extra work. Check below sample -

Lets say we have following Model -

```
public class DataModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public List<XhrViewModel> eles { get; set; }
}

public class XhrViewModel
{
    public string data1 { get; set; }
    public string data2 { get; set; }
}
```

and then we have following controller action which will return create view -

```
    public ActionResult CreateData()
    {
        DataModel m = new DataModel();
        m.eles = new List<XhrViewModel>();
        m.eles.Add(new XhrViewModel());
        m.eles.Add(new XhrViewModel());
        m.eles.Add(new XhrViewModel());
        return View(m);
    }
```

And the create view is pretty simple -

```
@model Rami.Vemula.Dev.Mvc.Controllers.DataModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CreateData";
}

<h2>CreateData</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitData", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>DataModel</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
            </div>
        </div>

        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.eles.Count; i++)
        {
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.eles[i].data1, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.eles[i].data1)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.eles[i].data1)
                </div>
            </div>
        }

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" id="ClickMe" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

If you check in the above View, **I used FOR loop instead of Foreach to render the child Model properties** i.e., xhrViewModel.

And on click of the submit button, you will hit SubmitData controller action -

```
    public ActionResult SubmitData(DataModel m)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Now when we run the application -

[image]

then on submit button, you get the values in the SubmitData controller action in this way -

[image]

Comment: To explain a little further ... what's getting posted back now are several keys like "m.value".  The model binder doesn't really know how to bind this back into the model.  If you use a for loop, each will look something like: Model.metric[1].value.  So it'll bind that right back into the model on post at the index of 1.

Comment: Yes I am in the process of giving you a simple code

Comment: @ErikElkins please check my updated answer. Hope it solves the problem.

Comment: @caj, are you able to find my answer helpful?

Comment: @ramiramilu I tried the for loop instead of the foreach and it's the same result, in the httppost actionresult the metric is null.

Comment: @ramiramilu I updated my post, I don't know if it makes any difference! Basically this view receives metric objects with the attribute name already chosen and I only need to insert a value for each metric object! Thank you!